# How to fix automatic view another activity on spinner onItemSelected methods

Tags: java, android

I'm working on simple android project that require spinner widget in android studio. what i want to do is, when a user select choices from the spinner it will open another activity. while i'm in the middle of the coding. I decided to use switch case condition with Intent. The problem is whenever i run the application it will automatically go to the specific activity location that i declare. Even though I didn't select any choice on spinner. 
Note: log cat doesn't show any error

Your help is very much appreciated to beginner like me.

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener extends Activity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                               long id) {

        // **************************** below here is where I start the new activity
        switch (pos) {
            case 0 :
                Intent i = new Intent(app.this, home.class);
                app.this.startActivity(i);
                break;

            case 1 :
                //Intent intent = new Intent(app.this, about.class);
                //app.this.startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case 2 :
                //Intent intent1 = new Intent(app.this, home.class);
                //app.this.startActivity(intent1);
                break;

        }
        // **************************** above here is where I start the new activity
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Please reTag your question!

Comment: @Aroniaina sorry what i mean is when ever i run the application it will automatically go to home.class. even though i didn't select first on spinner. Any idea how to fixed my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the application is created by default the first option is selected in your spinner and your listener is called. To avoid this you can use the solution of @Simon

or you can use a button to confirm your selection and change your activity when this button is pressed and not when an item is selected in your spinner.

**UPDATE**
You can also populate the first entry of your spinner with a useless text which can be a title like "Select activity" and start your switch in the listener to 1 and not 0

Comment: I already did the button sir and its working.. but what i want to do their is no button on it .. what i want is when user select any choices.. by default it will go to another activity

Comment: @J.Doe I updated my answer maybe the third solution will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Declare an int in your class, e.g. before `onCreate()`, then in your `onCreate()` you assign it to 0. Use this variable to check if its bigger than 0 when selecting something with your spinner, example below.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int spinnerCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSpinnerCheck = 0;

    mMySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int itemId = (int) id;

            // For some reason this method is called during initialization, so increment counter once to prevent it from auto selecting first item when loading view
            spinnerCheck += 1;

            if (spinnerCheck > 1) {
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent i = new Intent(app.this, home.class);
                        app.this.startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        //Intent intent = new Intent(app.this, about.class);
                        //app.this.startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        //Intent intent1 = new Intent(app.this, home.class);
                        //app.this.startActivity(intent1);
                        break;

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
   }
}
```

For some reason it selects the first item once created, not sure why, but this should work.

Comment: Thank you for reply but it result me a Force closed.. here is my logcat

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.joshua.myapplication.app.onCreate(app.java:22)

Comment: Line 22 is this sir  : spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

Comment: Thank you for your help sir,, its fine and working now :)!